# foreach loop with emply items Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach

this is my loop:

```
 $azienda = Azienda::where('id', $id_a)->get();
        foreach($azienda as $az){
            $id_azienda = $az->id; //code }
```

$azienda have empty items and this stop the loop...

How can i continue the loop and skip empty items ?

```
dd($aziendas->toArray());

    array:1 [▼
  0 => array:16 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "titolo" => "Studio Rossi"
    "categoria" => 1
    "logo" => "logonull.png"
    "descrizione" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pharetra,  n ▶"
    "indirizzo" => "via larga 1"
    "provincia_id" => 2
    "comune" => "Roma"
    "telefono" => "06 555444"
    "mobile" => "333 456789"
    "sitoweb" => "www.ldoksid.it"
    "email" => "ls*****@gmail.com"
    "remember_token" => null
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => "2017-09-27 16:13:57"
    "approved" => 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that when you say `has empty items` you mean that the model is actually empty - not hydrated with record from database - in which case you could filter records to only get the ones that actually have hydrated model:

```
$aziendas = Azienda::where('id', $id_a)->get();

$aziendas->filter(function(Azienda $azienda) {
    return $azienda->exists;
});
```

if it's some property on the instance of each model in the collection that might be empty - simply replace the logic within the closure i.e.

```
$aziendas = Azienda::where('id', $id_a)->get();

$aziendas->filter(function(Azienda $azienda) {
    return !empty($azienda->name);
});
```

or if it's relationship that might not have any associated records i.e. `Post` doesn't have any `Comment` then you can check it as:

```
$aziendas = Azienda::with('comments')->where('id', $id_a)->get();

$aziendas->filter(function(Azienda $azienda) {
    return $azienda->comments->count() > 0;
});
```

Please note I `Eager loaded` `comments` using `with('comments')` to make sure I only make 2 requests to the database rather than request for each iteration. Obviously you probably have a different relationship than `comments` - just replace it with the relevant one and from within the filter closure use relationship method's name as property to count associated records and only return the ones that actually have any associated records on that relationship.

You could also use `whereHas()` eloquent method to only fetch records that have specific relationship records - this would probably be a better option: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
$aziendas = Azienda::whereHas('comments')->where('id', $id_a)->get();
```

Comment: the records in database are not consecutive, so the loop go on for item id 1, item id 2 and stop because item id 3 doesn't exist but is item id 13.

Comment: hmm - if Item did not exist then how is it returned by eloquent? I'm really not sure how it `doesn't exist` - can you try and and `dd($aziendas->toArray())` and add them to your ticket so I can see exactly what it is you're getting back from this query?

Comment: is a pivot table...so i have id 1,2,3   id_azienda 1,2,13  and id_cliente 2,3,5

Comment: So you're trying to find out whether the relationship exists? If so you can check for the existence of this relationship using relationship method name as property. Make sure you eager load them to ensure you are not running query on the database with each iteration. More on that here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is use `continue`. This can be done as follows:

```
$azienda = Azienda::where('id', $id_a)->get();
        foreach($azienda as $az){
            $id_azienda = $az->id; //code 
            if (is_null($az) { continue; }
        }
```

However, I would also suggest you take advantage of Laravel's [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#available-methods). There is an [each](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-each) method:

```
$azienda->each(function ($item, $key) {
    // ..
});
```

Comment: how can i use continue?

Comment: Why this downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

To get the ids you can use pluck method.

```
$azienda = Azienda::where('id', $id_a)->get();

$ids = $azienda->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck

If you want just to break a loop, you can use 'break'.

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
 if($something..) {
    break;
 }
}
```

More info: http://php.net/break